# Flash and redirect_to in one line not producing flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, slim-lang

I have the following code

```
redirect_to questionnaire_url, error: "Now please fill in the questionnaire."
```

Normally if I set a `flash[:notice]` value above the redirect the flash shows on my page, however when I use the code above it doesn't.

My code to display the flash is

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
  = content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}")
```

After writing in `= flash.inspect` I received

```
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x000000044322f0 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=nil>
```

This is of course written using SLIM template language. My question is what is `notice` actually producing and how can I adjust my code to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: This code should work - can you check if anything is contained in `flash` after the redirect?

Comment: Quick question, if I was to replace notice with error then it wouldn't work as is.

Comment: Can you put a `= debug flash` in your view?

Comment: I used `= flash.inspect`. Results in the question.

Comment: shouldn't it be `redirect_to questionnaire_url, :notice => "Now please fill in the questionnaire."` ?

Comment: @jason328: when it was using `notice:` instead of `error:`, was `flash` empty at that time as well?

Comment: @PinnyM No, `notice` was working fine. It's `error` that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because [only `alert` and `notice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) can be used inline with `redirect_to` using this syntax.  For any other flash key, you need to specify:

```
redirect_to questionnaire_url, flash: {error: "Now please fill in the questionnaire."}
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `ApplicationController`:

```
add_flash_types :error
```